# Server side microsecond timing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Is there some API available for microsecond accurate timing?  Some jitter is acceptable.  Something equivalent to `performance.now()` is preferable.

In my 5 minutes of research I found the `console` object which does log times accurately enough but there is no easy way to retrieve those logged entries.  Additionally I may call this timing function thousands of times which would clutter logs.

Comment: Stackdriver's `console` object will be useful.

Comment: @tehhowch I see that stackdriver would provide a timestamp accurate enough and that I can log entries to stackdriver using the console object.  However, I do not see how to retrieve those logs.  Logging a timestamp and then retrieving it seems cumbersome and probably very slow to call the stackdriver API every time I would need a microsecond accurate timestamp.

Comment: Your question does not indicate that you intend to programmatically consume said resources. Perhaps you could edit it to be more specific about what you are trying to do, rather than ask a broad question and provide no research or links to related discussions you found?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is too broad.  However, I did say that I wanted something akin to `performance.now()` which does programmatically provide a microsecond accurate timestamp.  In my 5 minutes of searching I found the documentation for the `console` object but since it did not satisfy my requirements I did not include it in my original question.  

I don't think I need to provide the reasons for why I would need such a timestamp because I am only looking to see if such an interface exists.  If not, I will search for another solution on my own before returning here with another quetstion

Comment: You are asked to share your research, including things you found that are similar but don't work for you. Doing so prevents others from repeating your research back to you. Because you never showed you knew about `console.time` & `console.timeEnd`, I pointed you towards them. Sounds like you should write a simple label-based timing scheme, e.g. `function start(label) { db[label] = new Date().getTime(); } function stop(label) { const now = new Date().getTime(); const then = db[label]; return then ? now - then : 0; }`

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` returns an epoch in milliseconds which is not accurate enough for my needs - it may be sufficient to simply salt that epoch with a fake number of microseconds though.  I will include that research in the original question and keep it in mind as I use this site more - thanks.